# How to add a banner to a card in css

Tags: html, css

I want to add a banner to my cards on CSS but I am having trouble doing so. I am trying to create this effect

[banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSkNY.png)

I have tried creating a div and rotating it to fit on the car but cant seem to so

```css
    .wrapper-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    }

    
    .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .feature-banner{
     width: 10px;
     height: 25px;
     rotate: 60% left:
     cut-corners: true
    }
```

```html
    <body> 
      <div class="wrapper-flex">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="feature-banner">Featured!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Why is not working?

Comment: I think you need to use `transform:rotate(45deg)` you can look [about it at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate()#basic_example). There is no need for cutting corners, and I never saw a css property called cut-corners. I am curious, where did you find it?

Comment: @JaySurya I'm not sure but I think I saw on a video once